# Time axis for forest/tikz-qtree tree

Tags: forest, axis, tikz-qtree

How to draw this tree with a time axis where node lengths are automatically set according to the time? [image]

I want to superimpose this tree into the graph. Only the length of the terminal nodes (P, V, A, and B) need to be adjusted automatically according to their time (e.g., 1849, 1868). For A and B, time is not confirmed but A should be prior to P and V. And B should be prior to the rest.

I am able to make the tree using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newfontfamily{\smll}{CMU Sans Serif}[Scale=.8]

\begin{document}
\tikzset{baseline,every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{level distance=45pt, sibling distance=4pc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree[.$\alpha$ [.$\beta$ [.$\gamma$ [{P\\{\smll{CE 1849}}} ] [{V \\ {\smll{CE 1868}}} ] ] [.$\delta$ [\node(a){A}; ] ] ] [[\node(b){B}; ] ] ] 
\draw[dashed](b)..controls +(south:2) and +(south:1) .. (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Can you add a small document with a sample tree that you've created using `forest`? I assume you mean the height of the terminal nodes (leaf nodes) of the tree (P, V, A and B) not the non-terminal nodes? Does it need to be exactly proportional? And do you also want this to be superimposed onto the graph?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes Sir. You are absolutely right. I have edited the post with a basic code of the tree. The height of only the terminal nodes (leaf nodes) of the tree (P, V, A and B) should be adjusted according to the year. It is better if it is exactly proportional. And, yes, I want it to be superimposed on the timeline graph as shown in the picture. Thanks! :)